# Openxlsx: add new row on existing sheet

Tags: r, openxlsx

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets.
I load them to preserve the format.

`wb <- openxlsx::loadWorkbook(path_doc)`

... and now I want to add a new row on top of sheet 1. How can I do this ?
I can't find any useful function in package openxlsx to insert a new row.

Comment: I would work with the sheet as a data.frame (through `read.xlsx`) and then write it over the current sheet with `writeData`

Comment: @iago I can't do that if I want to save the formated cells in the initial workbook.